# How to set transport security in php web service request

Tags: php

I'm calling a web service in php and getting an error: "An error occurred when verifying security for the message"

I've come across this issue in .NET and *think* I know how to resolve it (by changing transport security type) but cannot work it out in php.  Here's the code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
class WsseAuthHeader extends SoapHeader
{
    private $wss_ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';
    function __construct($user, $pass, $ns = null)
    {
        if($ns)
        {
            $this->wss_ns = $ns;
        }
        $auth = new stdClass();
        $auth->Username = new SoapVar($user, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);
        $auth->Password = new SoapVar($pass, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);
        $username_token = new stdClass();
        $username_token->UsernameToken = new SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns);
        $security_sv = new SoapVar(
            new SoapVar($username_token, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns),
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'Security', $this->wss_ns
        );
        parent::__construct($this->wss_ns, 'Security', $security_sv, true);
    }
}

$username = "REDACTED";
$password = "REDACTED";
$wsse_header = new WsseAuthHeader($username, $password);
$options = array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'trace' => 1,
    'wdsl_local_copy' => true
);
// This is currently linked to the pilot or test site.
$wsdl = 'REDACTED';
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($wsse_header));
$objParam = new stdClass();
$objParam->ProfileIDVersion = new stdClass();
$objParam->ProfileIDVersion->ID = '0c5f1b29-e145-4dce-a058-0ebccbaa9ba4'; // This can be found via the admin portal of id3 global.
$objParam->ProfileIDVersion->Version = 0; //Setting this to zero will by default call the latest active version of the profile$objParam->CustomerReference particular customer
$objParam->InputData = new stdClass();
$objParam->InputData->Personal = new stdClass();
$objParam->InputData->Personal->PersonalDetails = new stdClass();
//$objParam->InputData->Personal->PersonalDetails->Title='Mr'; 
$objParam->InputData->Personal->PersonalDetails->Forename='Ruth'; 
$objParam->InputData->Personal->PersonalDetails->MiddleName=''; 
$objParam->InputData->Personal->PersonalDetails->Surname='Goodwin'; 
$objParam->InputData->Personal->PersonalDetails->Gender='Female'; 
$objParam->InputData->Personal->PersonalDetails->DOBDay='01'; 
$objParam->InputData->Personal->PersonalDetails->DOBMonth='12';
$objParam->InputData->Personal->PersonalDetails->DOBYear='1976';

$objParam->InputData->Addresses = new stdClass();
$objParam->InputData->Addresses->CurrentAddress = new stdClass();
$objParam->InputData->Addresses->CurrentAddress->Country='United Kingdom';
$objParam->InputData->Addresses->CurrentAddress->Street='High Street';
$objParam->InputData->Addresses->CurrentAddress->City='Westbury';
$objParam->InputData->Addresses->CurrentAddress->ZipPostcode='BA133BN';
$objParam->InputData->Addresses->CurrentAddress->Building='387'; 
$objParam->InputData->Addresses->CurrentAddress->SubBuilding=''; 





if (is_soap_fault($soapClient))
{
    echo "A";
    throw new Exception(" {$soapClient->faultcode}: {$soapClient->faultstring} ");
}
$objRet = null;
try
{
    $objRet = $soapClient->AuthenticateSP($objParam);
    echo '<pre>';
    print"Decision Band :".($objRet->AuthenticateSPResult->BandText)."<br>";
    echo '</pre>';
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    //echo "B";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($e);
    echo "</pre>";
}
if (is_soap_fault($objRet))
{
    echo "C";
    throw new Expception(" {$objRet->faultcode}: {$objRet->faultstring} ");
}
?>
```

---

Any ideas? I think I need to do something to change the security in the header to match the response from the service. I have a working C# implementation which uses the following binding, but I don't know how to get the same into php.

```
 <binding name="wsHttpBinding_GlobalAuthenticate">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: "An error occurred when verifying security for the message" - sorry, I will make that clearer in the question

Comment: `I've come across this issue in .NET and know how to resolve it (by changing transport security type)` sounds like you're asking the wrong question (there's actually no question asked in the question except "Any ideas?"). Please edit the title to be of the form 'how to do x?' and clarify in the question what you're trying to do. it won't be useful or meaningful to most readers that 'An error occurred when verifying security for the message' is the error message you're getting in the response.

Comment: @AD7six I can change the title of the post but I don't understand what you're asking aside from that. I am stating the nature of the error that is being returned. When I have encountered this same error before in C#, I was able to resolve it using a change in security binding. I don't know how to achieve the same thing in php, and my searches have been fruitless, possibly because it is handled in a completely different way. I'm guessing that this can be resolved in the same manner, so asking how to change security type might be the wrong way forward entirely. Better to share the actual issue.

Comment: That appears to be a [c# specific error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=An+error+occurred+when+verifying+security+for+the+message). At the moment to get an answer you need a reader who is all of: a php dev, c# familiar; familiar with soap requests. "How do I change this curl setting" (or similar) is a lot more likely to get an answer - make accessible to more people to answer your question :). I don't know what "changing transport security type" means myself.

Comment: Is this a PHP problem? There's no such error message in the PHP you posted. It looks like your webserver rejected the protocol used which happens before the php is executed. I think you should look at your webserver's list of acceptable protocols in the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for the steer @AD7six & @Simon; I guess something else is wrong and changing the binding is not the right way forward. Could this be a mismatch between SOAP versions?

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this message. But I have fixed it with a common change. Just you need to change this line.

private $wss_ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';

TO

private $wss_ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).